# Is there a point where $(f,g)=0$ on unit triangle

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal T = \{ (x,y)\in[0,1]^2 : x+y\leq 1 \}$ and let $h=(f,g) : \mathcal T\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be bounded,convex, continuous and such that $a\in f(\mathcal T)$ and $b\in g(\mathcal T)$ for some $(a,b)$. Now I know that $f(0,0)\geq a$ and $g(0,0)\geq b$ and for any $x+y=1$, $f(x,y)\leq a$ and $g(x,y)\leq b$.

I want to prove (or disprove) that there exists $(x,y)\in\mathcal T$ such that $h(x,y)=(a,b)$.

I was wondering is maybe I could use Brouwer fixed-point theorem, suppose there is no $(x,y)\in\mathcal T$ such that $h(x,y)=(a,b)$ and let $p(x,y)=\frac{1}{|f(x,y)-a| + |g(x,y)-b|} (|f(x,y)-a|, |g(x,y)-b|)$, this function is continuous from $\mathcal T$ to $\{ (a,b)\in\mathbb R^2 : a+b=1\}\subseteq\mathcal T$ since the denominator cannot be $0$. Now a point can be fixed only on $\{ (a,b)\in\mathbb R^2 : a+b=1\}$. I don't know if this reasoning can be finished, or mayhbe an other choice of function $p$ would fit better (or maybe using convexity would solve that easily).

Any help would be appreciated.